# Datacube listing products fails 'Platform not in index'

Tags: open-data-cube

ODC installation, Indexing and Ingestion complete for LANDSAT-8 SR products.
Now trying to execute notebooks for Cloud statistics computation using [data_cube_notebooks](https://github.com/ceos-seo/data_cube_notebooks/blob/master/notebooks/DCAL/DCAL_Cloud_Statistics.ipynb)
Responses of Notebook Cells included below:

```
#Get available products
products_info = dc.list_products()
print(products_info)

name                               
LS8_Ingested        
LS8_Ingested 

name description license
LS8_Ingested     Landsat 8 USGS Collection 1 Higher Level SR sc...    None
ls8_l2_c1_scene  Landsat 8 USGS Collection 1 Higher Level SR sc...    None 

name default_crs default_resolution                                                   
LS8_Ingested           None               None  
ls8_l2_c1_scene        None               None
```

Product definition is loaded from verified already available yaml files. Glimpse attached:

```
name: ls8_l2_c1_scene
description: Landsat 8 USGS Collection 1 Higher Level SR scene proessed using LaSRC. 30m UTM based projection.
metadata_type: eo

metadata:
    platform:
        code: LANDSAT_8
    instrument:
        name: OLI_TIRS
    product_type: LaSRC
    format:
        name: GeoTiff
```

Trying to list products:

```
# List LANDSAT 8 products
print("LANDSAT 8 Products:")
products_info[["platform", "name"]][products_info.platform == "LANDSAT_8"]
```

> KeyError: "['platform'] not in index"

1. Output of 'dc.list_products()' is dataframe with index(['name', 'description', 'license', 'default_crs', 'default_resolution'], dtype='object'). Surely there is no platform in index. How to add it then in index?

Answer (score 0):

Those notebooks are quite out of date. You can use it as an example, and adapt to your needs.

If you have an up to date version of Datacube, doing this will print a nice list of products and their respective information:

```py
import datacube
dc = datacube.Datacube()

dc.list_products()
```

Another minor concern I have is that you're using Collection 1 data with EO metadata. Collection 2 has been out for a while, and EO3 metadata types are more common. What you're doing will work, though.

[image]

Comment: So platform no more in INDEX? and Why default_crs and resolution are None in my case. Will changing metadata_type to eo3 will solve it as well.

Comment: Platform is no longer a field in this summary table.

The `default_crs` can be set in the product definition, but should only be set if the datasets all have a consistent CRS.

Comment: Any links to eo3 dataset metadata(yaml) and their preparation scripts.? (preferably for LS8 SR).

Comment: Can you ask a new question perhaps. Try to be clear and specific.